# Prossesing.org Minim input Serial

Tags: serial-port, arduino, processing, minim

I have set up an arduino with an electret microphone plugged into its analog input. Then I sent serial data over usb cable to processing.

Am trying to get minim(from processing.org library) to read this Serial data and perfom a spectrum analysis. But it seem to only accept signals from the sound card.

May I know if there is anyway for me to get minim to get a serial input?